# How to have a conditional aggregate lookup on a foreign key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

After many many tries, I can't have a nice conditional aggregation of my collections.

I use two collections :

**races** which have a collection of **reviews**.

I need to obtain for my second pipeline only the **reviews** published. 
I don't want to use a `$project`.
Is it possible to use only the `$match` ?
When I use localField, foreignField, it works perfect, but I need to filter only the published reviews.
I struggled so much on this, I don't understand why the `let` don't give me the foreignKey.
I tried : `_id`, `$reviews`, etc..

My `$lookup` looks like this :

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "reviews",
      as: "reviews",
      let: { reviewsId: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                // If I comment the next line, it give all the reviews to all the races
                { $eq: ["$_id", "$$reviewsId"] },
                { $eq: ["$is_published", true] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]

      // localField: "reviews",
      // foreignField: "_id"
    }
  },
```

Example of a **race** :

```
{  
   "description":"Nice race",
   "attendees":[  

   ],
   "reviews":[  
      {  
         "$oid":"5c363ddcfdab6f1d822d7761"
      },
      {  
         "$oid":"5cbc835926fa61bd4349a02a"
      }
   ],
   ...
}
```

Example of a **review** :

```
{  
   "_id":"5c3630ac5d00d1dc26273dab",
   "user_id":"5be89576a38d2b260bfc1bfe",
   "user_pseudo":"gracias",
   "is_published":true,
   "likes":[],
   "title":"Best race",
   "__v":10,
   ...
}
```

I will become crazy soon :'(...
How to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
        { $eq: ["$is_published", true] }
```

You are using this document `_id` field to match the reviews one.

The correct version looks like this:

```
(

    [
        { 
            "$unwind" : "$reviews"
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "reviews", 
                "as" : "reviews", 
                "let" : {
                    "reviewsId" : "$reviews"
                }, 
                "pipeline" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "$expr" : {
                                "$and" : [
                                    {
                                        "$eq" : [
                                            "$_id", 
                                            "$$reviewsId"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                     { $eq: ["$is_published", true] }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ], 
);
```

and now if your want to restore the old structure add:

```
{
  $group: {
           _id: "$_id",
           reviews: {$push: "$reviews"},
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! :) It helped me a lot !

Comment: Thank you again for your time. I have a problem in the $lookup. I grouped in the newt stage, but I have empty arrays maybe due to corrupted ids of reviews in races wich doesn't exist anymore. Do you have a solution for this ? And I would like maybe to keep a lookup wich also returns races without reviews.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to take correct field to get the data from the referenced collection i.e. `reviews`. And second you need to use [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) aggregation operator as your `reviews` field is an array of `ObjectId`s.

```
db.getCollection('races').aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "reviews",
    "let": { "reviews": "$reviews" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$reviews" ] },
        "is_published": true
      }}
    ],
    "as": "reviews"
  }}
])
```